# How to re-render a custom control when its sub-items and their properties change?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, dependency-properties

The original question was not knowing why the `PropertyChangedCallback` didn't fire, and it was caused by some code typos (too localized for SO).  However, I've modified the question to address how to re-render a custom control when it has sub-items that are added/removed, or if the sub-items have properties that are changed.  **Please [visit my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26132859/975724) to see in depth how to trigger the re-rendering.**

---

The title may not be the best description of the problem, however, the problem itself isn't very clear in anyway whatsoever.  I thought posting this question may be of some use because the PropertyChangedCallback is firing quite unpredictably.

I have the following structure for my custom control that I'm authoring:

- `MyControl : FrameworkElement`

  - `MyControl.Items`

    - `MyItem : FrameworkContentElement`

      - `MyItem.SubItems`

        - `MySubItem : FrameworkContentElement`
        - `MySubItem`
        - ....
    - `MyItem`
    - `MyItem`
    - ....

So basically, my control has a `DependencyProperty` which stores an `ObservableCollection<MyItem>`.
This `DependencyProperty` has a `PropertyChangedCallback` which is used to detect when the collection is set/unset.  This callback function is used to subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` events so that I can cause a re-render of my control when a `MyItem` is added/removed from the collection.

My control also should re-render when the collection items have a property that changes.  Therefore, `MyItem` also implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and I subscribe the `PropertyChangedEventHandler` when `MyItem` objects are added/removed to the collection.

So far, so good...

The `MyItem` class defines a few more `DependencyProperies`, each of which has the same `PropertyChangedCallback` function.  **To my suprise however, this callback function is not triggered when I modify one of the `MyItem` properties in XAML.**

What I'm hoping to learn is why this is happening and why the `PropertyChangedCallback` is not firing.  Also, I would like to know what scenarios can cause the callback to fire.

My goal is to have a control that re-renders when:
  *a) Its properties are changed*
  *b) Its children are added/removed*
  *c) Its children's properties are changed*
  *d) Its children's children are added/removed*
  *e) Its children's children's properties are changed.*

---

### Code Samples

Here is how I register the `MyControl.Items` property.  This `DependencyProperty` is **successful** at firing the property changed event.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Items", 
    typeof(ObservableCollection<MyItem>), 
    typeof(MyControl), 
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        null, //Default to null.  Instance-scope value is set in constructor.
        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, 
        OnItemsPropertyChanged));
```

This is how I respond to setting/unsetting of the `MyItems` collection:

```
private static void OnItemsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{   //This callback is called when ObservableCollection<MyItem> is set/unset.
    MyControl ctrl = (MyControl)obj;

    INotifyCollectionChanged oldList = args.OldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
    INotifyCollectionChanged newList = args.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;

    //If the old list implements the INotifyCollectionChanged interface, then unsubscribe to CollectionChanged events.
    if (oldList != null)
        oldList.CollectionChanged -= ctrl .OnItemsCollectionChanged;
    //If the new list implements the INotifyCollectionChanged interface, then subscribe to CollectionChanged events.
    if (newList != null)
        newList.CollectionChanged += ctrl .OnItemsCollectionChanged;
}
```

The following function is called when an item is added or removed from the `ObservableCollection<MyItem>`

```
private void OnItemsCollectionChanged(object source, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
{   //Invaliate the visual, causing it to re-layout and re-render.
    InvalidateVisual();

    //The contents of the Items collection was modified.
    //Subscribe/Unsubcribe to the PropertyChanged event as necessary.
    switch (args.Action)
    {
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
            foreach (MyItem mi in args.NewItems)
                mi.PropertyChanged += OnMyItemPropertyChanged;
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
            foreach (MyItem mi in args.OldItems)
                mi.PropertyChanged -= OnMyItemPropertyChanged;
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
            foreach (MyItem  mi in args.NewItems)
                mi.PropertyChanged += OnMyItemPropertyChanged;
            foreach (MyItem mi in args.OldItems)
                mi.PropertyChanged -= OnMyItemPropertyChanged;
                break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
            foreach (MyItem mi in (source as IEnumerable<MyItem >))
                mi.PropertyChanged += OnMyItemPropertyChanged;
            break;
    }
}
```

Now, I need to be able to react to when the `MyItem` has a property that changes.
Therefore, I established a callback function for when the `MyItem` has a `PropertyChanged` event:

```
private void OnMyItemPropertyChanged(object source, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{   //One of the MyItems had a property that was changed, 
    //invalidate the visual and re-render.
    InvalidateVisual();
}
```

The previous function is never called, because the `MyItem's` `DependencyProperties` never fire the property changed event.  Below illustrates how I've set up the `DependencyProperties` that I tried modifying in XAML:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyIntProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "MyInt", 
    typeof(int), 
    typeof(MyItem), 
    new PropertyMetadata(0, DependencyPropertyChanged));

public static readonly DependencyProperty MyDoubleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "MyDouble", 
    typeof(double), 
    typeof(MyItem), 
    new PropertyMetadata(0d, DependencyPropertyChanged));

public static readonly DependencyProperty MyStringProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "MyString", 
    typeof(string), 
    typeof(MyItem), 
    new PropertyMetadata("", DependencyPropertyChanged));
```

The following function is the callback for those `DependencyProperties`.  If fired, it should raise the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChangedEventHandler`:

```
private static void DependencyPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    MyItem item= (MyItem )obj;
    item.RaisePropertyChanged(args.Property.Name);
}

protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
{   //Notify listeners (such as the parent control) when a property changes.
    if(PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));;
}
```

Well... I have a similar set of events/handlers which are used for the `MyItem.SubItems` `DependencyProperty`, but at this point that isn't of any use.

If you are able to add any insight into how the `PropertyChangedCallback` works, I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks for reading this rather lengthy posts.

Comment: What is the reason for having dependency properties in `MyItem`? Couldn't it be standard CLR properties that raise the PropertyChanged event in their setter?

Comment: Well.  The main reason is so that MyItem can take in the binding system.  MySubItem, on the other hand is just a small piece of data, so it can have CLR properties only.  MyControl is a Graph, MyItem is a GraphLine, and MySubItem is a DataPoint.  The GraphLine has a few a few properties that control how it and its DataPoints graphically appear.  Perhaps this doesn't necessarily require data-binding, but ListBoxItem has a similar purpose as GraphLine.

Comment: @Clemens, Apparently, there is no problem with the code I have used.  My project had many typos, and thus the problem is too localized.  I've posted an in-depth tutorial on how to perform the goals described in the OP.  Thanks for your suggestion though ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I apologize, but the original question is too localized (small typos, and copy-paste errors).  However, to make this page useful, I have prepared a full explanation for how to create a custom control which has sub items or sub-sub items inside of it.  This page also explains how to configure each item so that property changes and collection changes cause a re-render on the original control.

First, the custom control must contain a `DependencyProperty` (and CLR-backed property) for a collection of items.  This collection should implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`, which makes `ObservableCollection` a good choice.  This collection should be parameterized to hold the sub items for the control.  Using the names from the original post, this requires code that looks like the following:

```
[ContentProperty("Items")] //This allows the "Items" property to be implicitly used in XAML.
public class MyControl : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Items", 
        typeof(ObservableCollection<MyItem>), 
        typeof(MyControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, OnItemsChangedProperty));

    //CLR-property.
    [Category("MyControl")]
    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> Items
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<MyItem>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    public MyControl() : base()
    {   //Set a new collection per control, but don't destroy binding.
        SetCurrentValue(ItemsProperty, new ObservableCollection<MyItem>());
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        //Draw stuff here.
    }

    //More methods defined later...
}
```

At this point, re-rendering is triggered when the `ObservabledCollection<MyItem>` is set and unset.
This collection is set automatically when the control is instantiated, which causes the first re-render.

Next, the collection should be monitored to detect when items are added and removed.  To do this, we must use the `PropertyChangedCallback` function that is provided to the `DependencyProperty`.
This function simply subscribes/unsubscribes to `CollectionChanged` events depending on if the collection of items is set or unset:

```
private static void OnItemsChangedProperty(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    MyControl ctrl = (MyControl)obj;

    INotifyCollectionChanged oldList = args.OldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
    INotifyCollectionChanged newList = args.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;

    //If the old list implements the INotifyCollectionChanged interface, then unsubscribe to CollectionChanged events.
    if (oldList != null)
        oldList.CollectionChanged -= ctrl.OnItemsCollectionChanged;
    //If the new list implements the INotifyCollectionChanged interface, then subscribe to CollectionChanged events.
    if (newList != null)
        newList.CollectionChanged += ctrl.OnItemsCollectionChanged;
}
```

And below is the callback function that handles when items are added/removed.  A re-render is triggered in here as well:

```
private void OnItemsCollectionChanged(object source, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    InvalidateVisual(); //Re-render MyControl

    switch (args.Action)
    {
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
            foreach (MyItem item in args.NewItems)
                item.PropertyChanged += OnItemPropertyChanged;
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
            foreach (MyItem item in args.OldItems)
                item.PropertyChanged -= OnItemPropertyChanged;
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
            foreach (MyItem item in args.NewItems)
                item.PropertyChanged += OnItemPropertyChanged;
            foreach (MyItem item in args.OldItems)
                item.PropertyChanged -= OnItemPropertyChanged;
                break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
            foreach (MyItem item in (source as IEnumerable<MyItem>))
                item.PropertyChanged += OnItemPropertyChanged;
            break;
    }
}
```

As you can see in the above function, the `PropertyChanged` event, which is defined in `MyItem` is subscribed/unsubscribed to as necessary so that the custom control can be notified when a property inside the `MyItem` class is changed.  This allows the control to re-render when it's sub-items have a property changed.

Here is the handler for when the sub-items' properties change:

```
private void OnItemPropertyChanged(object source, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    InvalidateVisual(); //Just re-render.
}
```

At this point the custom control will re-render as a result of the following situations:

- The `ObservableCollection<MyItem>` is set/unset.
- The `ObservableCollection<MyItem>` has an item added/removed, or if the collection is reset.
- The `ObservableCollection<MyItem>` has an item that has a property that is changed.

The final step to completing this explanation is to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface within the `MyItem` class.  The `PropertyChanged` event is simply invoked when any of the `DependencyProperties` is changed.  See the code below:

```
public class MyItem : FrameworkContentElement, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //INotifyPropertyChanged members:
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    //DependencyProperties
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyIntProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MyInt", 
        typeof(int), 
        typeof(MyItem), 
        new PropertyMetadata(0, DependencyPropertyChanged));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyStringProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MyString", 
        typeof(string), 
        typeof(MyItem), 
        new PropertyMetadata("", DependencyPropertyChanged));

    //Callback that invokes the INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChangedEventHandler
    private static void DependencyPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        MyItem item = (MyItem)obj;
        item.RaisePropertyChanged(args.Property.Name);
    }
}
```

If desired, this pattern can be repeated to allow sub-sub items to cause re-rendering of the custom control.  Simply establish a `DependencyProperty` in the first sub-item that contains another `ObservableCollection`, just like the `MyControl` class.  However, instead of causing a re-render directly when the sub-sub items have a `PropertyChanged` event, call the `RaisePropertyChanged` method to pass the notification back to the parent-most control.

I hope this helps any control authors manage the re-rendering of their controls! :)